# GRE over IPsec between Juniper SRX100 and Fortigate 100D

Tags: juniper, ipsec, fortigate, gre

I need assistance configuring VPN setup between Fortigate and Juniper devices (GRE over IPSec).

I have the topology as follows:

[image: Topology]

What I need to do is create a route-based IPSec tunnel between the devices to encapsulate another tunnel (GRE tunnel) within. I had similar setup between this Juniper and Cisco 2921 and it worked just fine, however, I am having real trouble setting this one up as I don't have necessary expertise with either.

Don't know if it is supposed to work that way, but...

- I want IPSec tunnel to be between 203.0.113.1 and 203.0.113.2 public addresses;
- I want GRE tunnel to initiate from loopback interface and communicate to remote endpoint's loopback (10.255.255.1 and 10.255.255.2) which I have routes for to reach via IPSec tunnel (st0.0 and ipsec interfaces accordingly);
- I want GRE interfaces to have IP addresses 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 respectively (and have OSPF running between these, configuration not included).

### **Juniper side**

**Interface configuration:**

```
interface fe-0/0/0 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 203.0.113.1/24;
        }
    }
}

interface lo0 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 10.255.255.1/32;
        }
    }
}

interface st0
    unit 0 {
        family inet;
    }
}

interface gr-0/0/0 {
    unit 0 {
        clear-dont-fragment-bit;
        tunnel {
            source 10.255.255.1;
            destination 10.255.255.2;
            allow-fragmentation;
        }
        family inet {
            mtu 1400;
            address 192.168.0.1/30;
        }
    }
}
```

**IKE configuration (edit security ike):**

```
proposal ike-prop {
    authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
    dh-group group5;
    authentication-algorithm sha1;
    encryption-algorithm aes-256-cbc;
    lifetime-seconds 28800;
}
policy ike-policy {
    mode main;
    proposals test-ike-prop;
    pre-shared-key ascii-text "test999";
}
gateway ike-gw {
    ike-policy test-ike-policy;
    address 203.0.113.2;
    dead-peer-detection;
    nat-keepalive 10;
    local-identity inet 203.0.113.1;
    remote-identity inet 203.0.113.2;
    external-interface fe-0/0/0.0;
    version v1-only;
}
```

**IPSec configuration (edit security ipsec):**

```
proposal test-ipsec-prop {
    protocol esp;
    authentication-algorithm hmac-sha1-96;
    encryption-algorithm aes-256-cbc;
    lifetime-seconds 3600;
}

policy ipsec-policy {
    perfect-forward-secrecy {
        keys group5;
    }
    proposals ipsec-prop;
}

vpn ipsec-vpn {
    bind-interface st0.0;
    df-bit clear;
    ike {
        gateway ike-gw;
        proxy-identity {
            local 10.255.255.1/32;
            remote 10.255.255.2/32;
            service junos-gre;
        }
        ipsec-policy ipsec-policy;
    }
    establish-tunnels immediately;
}
```

**Route configuration:**

```
routing-options {
    static {
        route 10.255.255.2/32 next-hop st0.0;
        #Default route exists, but not included
    }
}
```

**Firewall configuration:**

Firewall configuration not included, however, all traffic is permitted as follows:

> - From GRE to IPSec interface
> - From IPSec to GRE interface
> - From Wan1 to IPSec interface
> - From IPSec to Wan1 interface
> - From Loopback to IPSec interface
> - From IPsec to Loopback interface
> - From GRE to Protected network
> - From Protected network to GRE

### **Fortigate side**

**Interface configuration:**

```
config system settings
    set allow-subnet-overlap enable
end

config system interface
    edit "wan1"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 203.0.113.2 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping
        set type physical
        set weight 1
        set alias "WAN"
    next
    edit "ipsec"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 203.0.113.2 255.255.255.255
        set type tunnel
        set remote-ip 203.0.113.1
        set interface "wan1"
    next
    edit "gre"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.255
        set allowaccess ping ssh
        set type tunnel
        set remote-ip 192.168.0.1
        set mtu 1400
        set interface "ipsec"
    next
end

config system gre-tunnel
    edit "gre"
        set interface "ipsec"
        set local-gw 203.0.113.2
        set remote-gw 203.0.113.1
    next
end
```

**IKE configuration:**

```
config vpn ipsec phase1-interface
    edit "ike"
        set interface "wan1"
        set proposal aes256-sha1
        set peertype one
        set mode aggressive
        set localid "203.0.113.2"
        set remote-gw 203.0.113.1
        set peerid "203.0.113.1"
        set psksecret test999
    next
end
```

**IPSec configuration:**

```
config vpn ipsec phase2-interface
    edit "ipsec"
        set dst-addr-type ip
        set keepalive enable
        set phase1name "ike"
        set proposal aes256-sha1
        set protocol 47
        set src-addr-type ip
        set dst-start-ip 203.0.113.1
        set keylifeseconds 3600
        set src-start-ip 203.0.113.2
    next
end
```

**Route configuration:**

```
config router static
    edit 2
        set device ipsec
        set dst 10.255.255.1 255.255.255.255
    next
end
```

**Firewall configuration:**

Firewall configuration not included, however, all traffic is permitted as follows:

> - From GRE to IPSec interface
> - From IPSec to GRE interface
> - From Wan1 to IPSec interface
> - From IPSec to Wan1 interface
> - From Loopback to IPSec interface
> - From IPsec to Loopback interface
> - From GRE to Protected network
> - From Protected network to GRE

Please, advise if this kind of setup could at all work and what could be wrong here? I played with local/remote identities and could get IPSec to come up, show up in security-association table, however, never could get GRE interface to come up and have pingable remote address. Neither I could ping remote loopback via IPSec tunnel.

If any debug/output needed to troubleshoot just post in comments. Thanks!

Maybe you have some good resource on setting this up? Was not able to find anything on Fortinet/Juniper websites that would be helpful to setup between these two vendors. You can definitely find ones to setup with Cisco.

Note: addresses used are not public, but allocated for use in example code: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735

Comment: Why do you need to tunnel through a tunnel? That really doesn't make much sense. You can use the encrypted tunnel for the routing without a GRE tunnel.

Comment: As far as I know, IPSec doesn't support multicast, hence, GRE has to be used (maybe I'm wrong, however, don't really know how to setup OSPF, for example, in this case).

Comment: OSPF, and most routing protocols, can be set to use unicast for point-to-point (non-broadcast) links.

Comment: 1- why do you use aggressive mode w/ peer IDs on the FGT side? use main mode instead. 2- why re-use the WAN IP address on the IPsec interfaces?? you could use any (RFC1918) address range.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully, No. Stand the IPSec connection up. Then, if you need to create a GRE tunnel between other endpoints behind the IPSec peers, say from a pair of computers or something, simply configure the GRE tunnels on those devices.

You do not want or need to create an additional GRE tunnel on the IPSec devices themselves (since you already have a tunnel stood up - the IPSec tunnel).

Answer (score 0):

Juniper SRX Cannot terminate IPSEC and GRE in one interface where the fortigate has that feature called subnet overlapping which is not there in SRX .

The only way to do is create an loopback on fortigate and SRX devices respectively and give a try. Not many articles are available for this ( Hard to find).

I have given a clue.

Happy to help..

Regards,

Rajiv R

Comment: Not true - GRE over IPSEC is perfectly workable on the SRX, but there is no reason to do it just to run a routing protocol.

Answer (score 0):

IPSEC do not support multicast hence RIP,OSPF and EIGRP is out of question. If the requirement is excluding that then IPSEC would suffice.

Comment: This is simply not true.  In a Cisco environment or anywhere where you configure policy-based VPN then yes, you need to configure GRE over IPSEC so that you have a directly attached interface with the far side, but with every vendor that supports route-based VPN, RIP and OSPF will run perfectly fine directly over the tunnel interface.  We use this functionality in our office today and have done for some years.